# AWS Lambda NET: How to select connection string

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I develop AWS Lambda NET Core svc. It allows to be run in a local environment during the development and can be deployed to AWS . I use Connection string in appsettings.json like

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LocalConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"
"RDSConnection": "Server=xxxxxxx;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=xez;Password=xez;"
  }
```

I can add there yet another connection string to the real RDS database. But how to select in the app what string do I need? I.e. I do

```
var connectionString = _configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["LocalConnection"];
```

How to select the LocalConnection string if the app in the local env and rds connection string if the app works in AWS?
In other words: how to detect inside the app if it works in a local environment or in AWS?

Comment: When an AWS Lambda function is invoked, it provides two input parameters: `context` and `event`. You could use the [AWS Lambda context object in C# - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-context.html) to obtain information about the environment, which will of course be different when you invoke your code outside of AWS Lambda.

Comment: How to obtain these parameters (context and event) in NET 6 Service running as a Lambda? I use the VS 2022 AWS  Template for creating the NET Core service and plan to deploy it to AWS as Lambda

Comment: I'm not familiar with ".NET 6 Service running as a Lambda", but these parameters provide the context and the trigger event for a Lambda function. That service _might_ provide something similar.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your `IConfiguration` object like this:

```cs
Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder() 
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())  
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();
```

In this case, configuration is first searched into `appsettings.json` and then into environment variables. If keys are found in environment variables, previous configuration is overridden.

#### Local appsettings.json

With this setup, you just need to maintain one property in `appsettings.json` for your local configuration.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=db;User Id=postgres;Password=postgres;"
}
```

#### AWS Configuration

When Lambda is deployed on AWS, you can create an environment variable there with name `ConnectionStrings:DBConnection` to hold your production RDS connection string. This way, environment variables will take the priority and local `appsettings.json` will be ignored when running the Lambda function on AWS.

You can also checkout my blog post here for detailed information - [Implementing Configuration, Logging & Dependency Injection in AWS Lambda using .NET Core](https://coderjony.com/blogs/implementing-configuration-logging-dependency-injection-in-aws-lambda-using-net-core?source=stackoverflow)

Comment: Thank you for the blog link, it is interesting, also, I am searching the way how to use logging in Lambda, where to write them